# htaccess Mod-Rewrite (GET parameters + on top of rewrite)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I'm working on this application and I'm having a little issue regarding htaccess mod_rewrite.

Before I explain what I want to do I'll show you what I've done so far:

```
RewriteRule ^client([0-9]*)$ index.php?clientID=$1
```

This essentially allows me to use **url.com/client5** instead of **url.com/clientID=5**, that works perfectly. But lets say I would like to actually use GET variables and do something like **url.com/client5?page=main**, would it be possible to achieve that, if not anyone could suggest an alternative approach?

Thank you!!!

Please bare in mind that the .htaccess file is stored in the root dir meaning it will affect all of the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `[qsappend]`.

```
RewriteRule ^login.html$ ?action=login [qsappend]
```

You can call it like. .com/login.html?page=main